# Resolve abstract class based on generics

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container

I want to resolve an abstract class using Unity.
The abstract class has implementations that have certain generics. For example:

```
public abstract class Iface<S, T> where S : SomeClass where T : OtherClass

public class face : Iface<SomeClassExample, OtherClassExample>
```

Then I want to execute:

```
UnityContainer.Resolve<Iface<SomeClassExample, OtherClassExample>>();
```

But it gives the error Exception is:

> InvalidOperationException - Instances of abstract classes cannot be created.

Which is obvious, because I want to create an abstract class. I hoped Unity would be smart enough to find the specific class based on the generics. Is is possible to do something like this?

Comment: unity is a dependency injection container, not a magic lamp. register implementations through reflection for example.

Comment: yes you need to register `face` with Unity and tell it to use `face` whenever code asks for `Iface<SomeClassExample, OtherClassExample>`

Comment: If you need to register face, then what is the point of using reflection here? I might as well call new face()<SomeClassExample, OtherClassExample>;

Comment: @Wouter Clearly you are using DI then without understanding it yet - which is ok. Not an easy topic. The difference is that you are supposed to work with interfaces instead of concrete implementations, while your testing environment + production environment have seperate registration routines. So using Resolve<IFace...>() is correct way of doing DI. google "DI unity register by convention" to check for guidance. There are plenty DI Containers which provide a very different set of features regarding registration.

Comment: @Dbl Thanks for your reply. You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly register the face class and map it with the correct generics.

```
UnityContainer.RegisterType<Iface<SomeClassExample, OtherClassExample>, face>();
```

Even though, I believe it should be possible for Unity to recognize the correct class that belongs to certain generics automatically...

Edit:
There actually is a way!

```
UnityContainer.ConfigureAutoRegistration().Include(type => type.ImplementsOpenGeneric(typeof(Iface<,>)), Then.Register().AsFirstInterfaceOfType()).ApplyAutoRegistration();
```

It automatically registers all generic derived classes that implement this base class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly ask it to resolve to your `face` class. Just looking at the error message, it is trying to create an instance of `Iface<SomeClassExample, OtherClassExample>`

```
UnityContainer.Resolve<face<SomeClassExample, OtherClassExample>>();
```

If you want to use Iface as an interface — Create an interface and register it